# Find out max available year and then show all records between two years

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select from a table the max available year and based on the max year to show results for 10 years back.

Ideally, something like this

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | year       |    data    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2008       |   12453    |
|  2 | 2019       |   12453    |
|  3 | 2005       |   12453    |
|  4 | 2000       |   12453    |
|  5 | 2018       |   12453    |
|  6 | 2020       |   12453    |
|  7 | 2021       |   12453    |
+----+------------+------------+
```

1. Find out the max year - in this case, `2021`
2. Select everything between `2021` and `2011`(including both - start and end years)

In this case, the result should be

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | year       |    data    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  2 | 2019       |   12453    |
|  5 | 2018       |   12453    |
|  6 | 2020       |   12453    |
|  7 | 2021       |   12453    |
+----+------------+------------+
```

What I have so far is this

```
SELECT MAX(year) as last_year, MIN(year) as first_year 
FROM data_table t1
INNER JOIN administrator t2 ON t1.id=t2.id 
WHERE dates IS NOT NULL 
between t1.last_year - 10
GROUP BY t2.id
```

The error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'between t1.last_year - 10

Comment: Please make this a complete question by including sample data for _both_ tables involved.  You haven't done that.  Instead, you showed the output from the join.

Comment: Sorry @TimBiegeleisen, I didn't tough that it is important since I need just the year and data. Actually I will probably remove the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data sample you gave, this

```
select * from table_name
where year >= (select max(year) from table_name) - 10
```

should return the expected output.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df7ddf490dbacba6c9b424d94c50a339)

Comment: Works correctly. Thanks!